# gRPC client is slower in C++ than using `ghz` with the same count of threads

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a C++ client to benchmark a gRPC server.

4 poller threads are running concurrently on the client.

Each thread run concurrently 100 asynchronous request using its own channel and stub, and per-thread RPS is then aggregated.

When using this code, I achieve 90K RPS, but when using [ghz](https://ghz.sh), I achieve 150K RPS when using the same count of threads and connections (`--connections=4 --cpus=4`).

```cpp
struct RPC
{
    MessageEcho response;
    grpc::ClientContext context;
    std::unique_ptr<grpc::ClientAsyncResponseReader<MessageEcho>> reader;
    grpc::Status status;
};

void run_client_thread(const Config& config, ThreadRes& res, int n_concurrents)
{
    grpc::CompletionQueue cq;

    auto enqueue_new_rpc = [&](RPC* rpc) {
        rpc = new(rpc) RPC{};
        rpc->reader = stub.AsyncEcho(&rpc->context, res.payload, &cq);
        rpc->reader->Finish(&rpc->response, &rpc->status, rpc);
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < n_concurrents; i++)
    {
        enqueue_new_rpc(static_cast<RPC*>(::operator new(sizeof(RPC))));
    }

    const Timespec start = Timespec::now();

    while(keeprunning)
    {
        void* got_tag;
        bool ok = false;

        auto deadline = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(300);
        const grpc::CompletionQueue::NextStatus status = cq.AsyncNext(&got_tag, &ok, deadline);
        if(status == grpc::CompletionQueue::GOT_EVENT && ok)
        {
            RPC* const rpc = static_cast<RPC*>(got_tag);
            if(rpc->status.ok())
            {
                res.n_success++;
            }
            else
            {
                res.n_fails++;
            }

            rpc->~RPC();
            enqueue_new_rpc(rpc);
        }
        else if(status == grpc::CompletionQueue::TIMEOUT)
        {
            res.n_timeouts++;
        }
        else
        {
            res.n_fails++;
        }
    }

    const Timespec stop = Timespec::now();
    const double elapsed = stop.difftime_s(start);
    res.requests_per_sec = static_cast<double>(res.n_success) / elapsed;

    cq.Shutdown();
}
```

Is there any obvious performance issue in this code?

Additional notes:

- When profiling, I see that the CPU is under-utilized compared to ghz
- How the channels are distributed (every thread has its own channel, or sharing the channel/stub) doesn't affect performances.